# trouble sending email using python SMTP

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

So I'm having trouble finding what this error is:

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (235, 'welcome')
```

I can't find a clear answer what 235 is anywhere.

So I do something along the lines of the following:

```
s = smtplib.SMTP()
s.connect("smtp.myserver.com", 25)
```

With a reply of (220, 'Welcome to the 9x SMTP Server')

Then I do:

```
s.ehlo()
```

and get back

```
(250, 'p3\nAUTH LOGIN\nHELP')
```

I did this because the server doesn't support starttls

```
smtplib.SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

Then I try to log in:

```
>>> s.login("test@myserver.com", "password")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 608, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (235, 'welcome')
```

I don't know what 235 means, but I get a welcome string. I'm really confused, I'm 100% sure my credentials are correct.

Comment: were you calling `s.ehlo()` before `s.starttls()`?

Comment: In this example yes, but even if I call starttls before ehlo, I get the same error.

Comment: "*235 2.7.0  Authentication Succeeded This response to the AUTH command indicates that the authentication was successful.*" - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4954#section-6

Comment: Yes but python raises an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your server's response to the `AUTH LOGIN` command is atypical, and perhaps non-standard.

The typical pattern is this:

```
C: AUTH LOGIN xxxx
S: 334 yyyy
C: zzzz
S: 235 welcome
```

Where `C` indicates the client, `S` indicates the server, `xxxx` is the base64-encoded user name, `yyyy` is an ignorable base64-encoded string, and `zzzz` is the base64-encoded password.

Your server is instead doing this:

```
C: AUTH LOGIN xxxx
S: 235 welcome
```

For whatever reason, your server doesn't appear to be interested in the password.

I do not know what configuration change you might need on your server. If you are interested in modifying smtplib.py, look for this code:

```
    elif authmethod == AUTH_LOGIN:
        (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH",
            "%s %s" % (AUTH_LOGIN, encode_base64(user, eol="")))
        if code != 334:
            raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
        (code, resp) = self.docmd(encode_base64(password, eol=""))
```

and try something like this instead:

```
    # UNTESTED
    elif authmethod == AUTH_LOGIN:
        (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH",
            "%s %s" % (AUTH_LOGIN, encode_base64(user, eol="")))
        if code == 334:
            (code, resp) = self.docmd(encode_base64(password, eol=""))
        elif code != 235:
            raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
```

On the other hand, modifying your program probably makes more sense. Try this:

```
#s.login("test@myserver.com", "password")
code, resp = s.docmd('AUTH LOGIN', encode_base64('test@myserver.com'))
if code==334:
    # Probably won't happen on "the 9x SMTP Server"
    code, resp = s.docmd(encode_base64('password'), '')
if code!=235:
    raise smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
```

Reference:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433484(v=exchg.80).aspx
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.docmd

Comment: Thanks for your long post. It was really helpful. It didn't work unfortunately because I get a str object not having an attribute 'get_payload'

Comment: Or maybe there's a way to use my smtp server without requiring a password? I can't figure out the configuration at the moment. It would be cool to have an open SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to perform additional settings required by your SMTP. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.ehlo), since you are using `ehlo` you can perform such setup by changing `s.esmtp_features` dictionary.

Example:

```
s.esmtp_features["auth"] = "LOGIN DIGEST-MD5" # changing the authentication method
```